# Why do I have no TTY on a basic Ubuntu 9.10 server install?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 9.10 Server several times on a bog standard 1RU server and each time I finish the install and reboot I see GRUB run and am then presented with a black screen. The machine is running just fine, as I am able to SSH in, but I can't see anything on the attached monitor. I have a simple LCD screen connected via VGA and a signal is apparently being output to it, as it doesn't go asleep.

Looking at `/var/log/syslog` I see:

> Mar 24 14:57:44 bridge5 rsyslogd-2039: Could no open output file '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]

However, I later see:

> Mar 24 14:57:44 bridge5 kernel: [    0.001368] console [tty0] enabled

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: xconsole is unimportant; it's meant as a buffer for the xconsole utility from x11-apps, and isn't created in ubuntu. You can remove it from `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`.

Comment: Perhaps it is simply defaulting to the blank tty that's reserved for X11 (which provides the GUI, and which is not installed by default for Ubuntu server). What happens when you press Alt+F1? Does that enable you to log in?

Comment: "console [tty0] enabled" there is no tty0, the ttys start at tty1 usually. Does alt-f2 show a login prompt? Is there a line for tty1 /etc/inittab (or in /etc/init, but as it's 9.10 it probably still is inittab).

Answer (score 1):

tty0 is usually used for a serial console.  Check your config for tty0 and tty1 by looking at /etc/init/tty0.conf and /etc/init/tty1.conf respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring Grub to use a specific screen resolution. See this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/66428/how-can-i-change-console-shells-resolution-in-ubuntu-9-10) on superuser for further info.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that seems to have no effect. Likewise disabling the graphical console...